# Speed control of UR in Simulation and RealLife

Tags: ros, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

i’m simulating a ur10 in Gazabo. Unfortunately i don’t know hai to set its speed. The default one that is set when using the Description Pkg form UR and the Gazebo Sim PKG from UR is very slow.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/418160/speed-control-of-ur-in-simulation-and-reallife/) by [Icon45](https://answers.ros.org/users/151050/icon45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2023-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using MoveIt, I think there is a default speed scaling of 10% that can be increased from a dialog box in the motion planning settings.

---

Originally posted by [danzimmerman](https://answers.ros.org/users/37963/danzimmerman/) with karma: 337 on 2023-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1